# ¿Cómo llamo un objeto que ya está creado en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Necesito saber como invoco un objeto ya creado en un archivo diferente utilizando el POO. Ejemplo: tengo una clase llamada `person.php`:

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public $firstName = 'John';
    public $lastName = 'Doe';
    private $dateOfBirth = '1980-12-01';

    public function __construct($fisrtName, $lastName, $dateOfBirth)
    {
        $this->fisrtName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;
    }

    public fuction setlastName(firstn)
    {
        $this->firstName= $firstn
    }

    public function getfirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public fuction setlastName(lastn)
    {
        $this->lastName= $lastn
    }

    public function getlastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getDateOfBirth()
    {
       return $this->dateOfBirth;
    }

    public function setDateOfBirth($date)
    {
        $this->dateOfBirth = $date;
    }
}
```

Y tengo otro archivo que se llama ingreso de persona, que es donde inserto los datos de esta manera `ingreso.php`:

```
include("person.php");     
$persona1= new person("Julio","Ramirez","10-DIC-2016");
```

pero tengo otro archivo que se llama `mostrar.php`, y no se como obtener los datos que ya inserté en `person.php`, para luego mostrarlos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.properties-methods) y que si usas "getters" y "setters" uses los atributos con modificador de acceso `private`. Otra cosa que debes considerar, es que los objetos que crees en php se destruyen al concluir la petición http, para que los datos permanezcan debes almacenarlos en otra fuente (base de datos, archivos de texto, variables de sesion, cookies, etc). Si no es lo que necesitas, quizá puedas explicar tu duda de otra manera.

Comment: solo incluye tu archivo en mostrar.php, es decir en mostrar include(ingreso.php)